# rstudio cannot run knitr

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, package

I've updated RSTUDIO to 1.0.143 and now knitr will not work:

Beginning of messages:

> evaluate 0.8 is required but 0.7 is available
>       htmltools 0.3.5 is required but 0.2.6 is available
>       jasonlite ...
>       base64encode ...
>       rprojroot 1.0 is not available

I have tried stuff like update.packages()  update.packages("evaluate") install.packages("evalute") (which installs version 0.7) on  a few repositories without luck. (Global.rstudio, USA (IA))

I don't understand the ecosystem and I'm not finding any useful info from knitr or rstudio websites - how to I proceed?

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
>   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
>   locale:
>   [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] knitr_1.10.5

Comment: I suspect the current R version is around 3.4.1 so a good start would be updating r-base and then updating packages

Comment: Yep, the old version of R is preventing you from installing new versions of the packages.

Comment: Thanks!! I wasted a lot of time, but I now see the unhighlighted footnote "Rstudio requires R2.11.1+"  on the download page.  I didn't understand that RStudio was separate from R.

Comment: Maybe someone should update and or elaborate on that footnote on the Rstudio download page since R2.11.1 is not current?